# Crate PDO driver installation using composer.phar fails

Tags: php, pdo, crate, amphp, artax

I'm trying to install the Crate PDO driver from here: https://github.com/crate/crate-pdo

The manual says to use composer.phar like so:

> php composer.phar require crate/crate-pdo:~0.0.3

However, that produces the following:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> ```
> Problem 1
> - Installation request for crate/crate-pdo 0.0.7.* -> satisfiable by crate/crate-pdo[0.0.7].
> - crate/crate-pdo 0.0.7 requires amphp/artax 1.0.0-rc4 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>    see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
> ```

I've looked at the minimum-stability setting, but am unsure how to use that (where exactly do I set that). This is also my first time using composer, so perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

First go ahead and grab amphp/artax:~1.0.0-rc2

```
php composer.phar require amphp/artax:~1.0.0-rc2
```

Then go ahead and do:

```
php composer.phar require crate/crate-pdo:~0.0.3
```

If that doesn't work, then edit composer.json and add in the req for those projects:

```
{
    "require": {
        "crate/crate-dbal": "~0.0.4",
        "amphp/artax": "~1.0.0-rc2"
    }
}
```

The problem is that composer can't resolve the amphp/artax package for some reason.

**Edit**

As of [1/8/2015 there's a fresh release](https://github.com/crate/crate-pdo) on git that does not require the work around described above. Simply require crate and run composer update.

Comment: JFYI: We are currently replacing the artax http client by another one, so after the next pdo release (which will happen soon), this issue should be gone.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I do have new php errors now though. If I manage to solve those, I'll post a link here.

Comment: @SebastianUtz That's awesome! I wasn't expecting to see you respond here. Keep up the great work!

Comment: We've just released v0.1.0 which fixes this issue.